# CDK Route53 CNAME test fails, expected and received name seem equal

Tags: aws-cdk

I have this test:

```
test('Test if the CNAME record is created', () => {
  template.resourceCountIs('AWS::Route53::RecordSet', 1);
  template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::Route53::RecordSet', {
    Name: 'presentation.cloud101.nl',
    Type: 'CNAME',
    TTL: '300',
  });
});
```

And this code:

```
new CnameRecord(this, 'Cloud101DistributionAlias', {
  recordName: `presentation.cloud101.nl`,
  domainName: distribution.domainName,
  zone: hostedZone,
  ttl: Duration.seconds(300),
});
```

And the test fails with this message:

> `Expected presentation.cloud101.nl but received presentation.cloud101.nl.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while writing this question I found out why, and I want to share this with the next poor soul that runs into this.

> `!!   Expected presentation.cloud101.nl but received presentation.cloud101.nl.`

The error message is actually completely correct in telling you the difference: `.`

In a CName record the `.` at the end is automatically set by Amazon. As you can see, I did not specify it in my CDK code nor in my test code but it was added anyway. This is confusing to say the least (especially because it is at the end of the sentence in the error output). But it comes down to the fact that adding the `.` in the test is mandatory to make it green.

Why is this behavior the way it is? I guess they had to make a choice. The official implementation of Route53 does not care about the `.` they say.

> A trailing dot is optional; Amazon Route 53 assumes that the domain name is fully qualified. This means that Amazon Route 53 treats [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (without a trailing dot) and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). (with a trailing dot) as identical.

[Official AWS R53 documentation on this topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html)